# Regarding Writing a Custom Class Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception, reflection, throw

I am trying to complete an activity that my professor for my Computer Science course has assigned, and I am not quite sure what he means by this, look at number 4:

[image]

Here is what i have so far:

```
package ExceptionsActivity;

public class Exceptions {

public static void f1(int x) throws XisFiveException{
    if (x == 5){
        throw new XisFiveException("X cannot be 5");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Success, x = ");
    }
}

public static void f2_1(int x) throws XisFiveException{
    try {
        f1(x);
    } 
    catch (XisFiveException e) {
        f1(x + 1);
    }
}

public static void f2_2(int x) throws XisFiveException{

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

}

}
```

As you can see I have wrote the method f1 and f2_1 which is what question number 2 is asking for. I intended on putting the solution for question four in f2_2. I am not quite sure what to do for number 4 and any advice as to what direction to head in would greatly be appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is trying to help you understand exception handling. You have a method that throws an exception named `f1`. There are two ways methods calling `f1` can deal with this. They can catch it or they can throw it back to the method calling them. The first looks like this:

```
//note that I have removed the "throws" from the method declaration
public static void f2_1(int x) {
    try {
        f1(x);
    } 
    catch (XisFiveException e) {
        f1(x + 1);
    }
}
```

And the second looks like this:

```
public static void f2_2(int x) throws XisFiveException{
    f1(x);
}
```

Again, the difference is that one handles the exception with a try catch block, and the other simply passes the exception up to whatever method called it. These should help you with your problem, but like your professor said, the important thing is to understand the different ways you can deal with an exception.

Comment: Thank you for the response! One question though, why did you erase the throws from the method declaration? In eclipse when i remove it, the     f1(x + 1) no longer compiles, it says "unhandled exception type XisFiveException." Any input on this? Thanks!

Comment: @Biggytiny you're right - the throws is needed, but not for the first f1(x) call. It is needed for the second call, f1(x+1). good catch. the important thing to note about this example is it is a little confusing. normally if you handle an exception with a try-catch, you do not need to still declare that your method throws the exception. in this case you do, though, because the catch() calls the f1 method again

Comment: @Biggytiny No problem, happy to help. If my answer helped you it would be cool if you accepted it as a solution.